# How to create a Spring boot project in a PC which never has Internet access, works on Intranet (LAN) and does not have Maven or Gradle installed?

Tags: spring-boot

What I tried:

I downloaded a spring boot project from an Internet-connected machine and tried mailing the same to the never-Internet-connected PC, but the ZIP file never goes through.